# Ruby directly from command line

Tags: ruby

I know that I can run ruby code directly from the command line, like so:

```
ruby file.rb
```

But is there any way to run ruby code directly from the command line so that I don't have to save the file in the first place?

Comment: Did you try irb...Its the ruby console...

Comment: Sure, but that is not what I'm asking.

Comment: Directly ... from where?

Comment: Can yo be more precise on your question please...It's really difficult to answer when we have a broader context.

Comment: @Kryzysztof Safjanowski From the command line without saving to a file.

Comment: I have to agree, Vamsi answered correctly. That's exactly what you were asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ruby -e 'puts("foobar :)"); puts(2 + 2)'`

should print `foobar :)` and `4`

Comment: @ljnissen Keep in mind this is for unusual situations, and shouldn't be a matter of habit.

Comment: You can also do multiple -e for multiline program...`ruby -e 'puts "test"' -e 'puts 2+2'` But, I would'nt recommend this approach at all...May be if you can let us know your use case, that can help people give better options...

Comment: A bit of googling gave me this: First type `ruby` in the command line, then copy and paste the code and finally ctrl-d and return.

Answer (score 1):

The quick help invoked using `ruby -h` says:

```
$ ruby --help
Usage: ruby [switches] [--] [programfile] [arguments]
  ...
  -e 'command'    one line of script. Several -e's allowed. Omit [programfile]
  ...
```

[@djaszczurowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095778/4265352) provides you an example.

Another, better, option is to use `irb` (the interactive Ruby interpreter). It displays a prompt and waits for you to enter Ruby code. Multiple lines of code can be entered; it is executed when the block is closed.

[@ho-man's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45096238/4265352) shows you how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more code that you'll like to run you can use `irb` instead.

```
$ irb
2.4.1 :001 > puts (2+2)
4
 => nil
```